# Query to return only part of a value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to return a part of a value in a collection in a manner similar to a capturing group in a regular expression? For instance, if I have values like:

```
MyKey: "PrefixDataIDontCareAbout-DataIDoCareAbout-OtherDataIDontCareAbout"
```

Is there a way to return just the **DataIDoCareAbout** portion using regex or some other method? Substrings won't work because the data I need to extract is more complex than just a fixed range of characters. And this would need to be done at the query level because I need to group them as distinct so the same value will only show once.

Any tips would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to create javascript script that would run multiple queries: first that would be able to acquire the "**DataIDoCareAbout**" part and next, that would run distinct and other stuff you really need using the results.

Answer (score 1):

No, and largely requiring to do that signals a problem in your data model, you would be better served to refactor your model to leave **DataIDoCareAbout** as a separate, perhaps indexable, key.

Comment: The problem is the **DataIDoCareAbout** is dynamic and changes from query to query. There's no way to set it aside.

Answer (score 0):

Not in regex style no.

There is only the `$substr` command built into the aggregation framework that would be of any use here however this only runs over integer position of characters within a string.

I also would not regex this depending upon your queries. If you limit the query by other fields then it should be ok, i.e. user_id and regex however using a regex, in none-prefixed format as you would have to, could be very slow.